# cannot login to my imac running 10.4

Tags: macos, mac, imac

I have an iMac with OS X 10.4 that I can't login to. Whenever I get to the login page I type my password and it starts to login. The blue and white status bar appears and eventually login but only for a split second. A blank blue screen flashes and then it returns to the login screen. This only occurs with the admin account. Any ideas on how to stop this?

Comment: Is something interesting showing up in the log files in `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`? Do you have a second admin account? Can you authenticate from another (regular) account to e.g. change settings in System Preferences? Do you have FileVault activated on your admin account?

Answer (score 1):

Try rebooting in Safe mode by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> as the Mac starts to boot -- this will disable several categories of system add-ons (see Apple's [KB #HT1455](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455) and [#1564](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564)) that're likely suspects with a problem of this sort.  If that works (i.e. lets you log in), look through the various things that were disabled, and experiment with removing them some at a time to isolate what's causing the problem.  Since it's only one account having trouble, things inside the user Library are the most likely suspects.